# Can't run the newest version of MySQL on phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am building a database on phpMyAdmin. However, it doesn't include the latest version of MySQL:[image]

I downloaded the latest version of MySQL from this link: [MySQL Community Server 8.0.16](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

However, even after I installed it I cannot find a way to change it on phpMyAdmin since when I open wamp, go to MySQL --> Version the only version that appears is 5.7.26. So how can I update it to the latest one? I am running it on Windows 10.

Comment: Perhaps you have both 5.7 and 8.0 installed??

Comment: @RickJames If I let only the file with the 8.0 version of MySQL then phpMyAdmin doesn't recognise it. How can i fix that?

Comment: What OS are you running? How did you install the new version of MySQL?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ I am running Windows 10 and I downloaded and installed MySQL 8.0 from the link that I mentioned above

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ Do you know how I change the version?

Comment: Do you have any data?  The following steps may lose the data.  Uninstall 5.7; then see if you can get to 8.0